# Json import to postgresql with python

Tags: python, json, postgresql

I'm trying to import multiple json files into my postgres Database with the following code.

```
import json
import psycopg2


con = psycopg2.connect(database="kw_du", user="postgres", password="f67dd8hzFE5",host="localhost")


cur = con.cursor()
with open(r"C:\Users\diego\OneDrive\Desktop\Workplace\220906\nu_2022_09_01.json", 'r') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

with con.cursor() as cur:
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test_nu(vp_ip, system_activ, vpm_activ) VALUES(%s)', [(json.dumps(d),) for d in data])

con.commit()
con.close()
```

The json file has the following structure:

```
[{"vp_id":1,"system_activ":1,"vpm_activ":1},{"vp_id":2,"system_activ":2,"vpm_activ":2}]
```

When executing the code i get the following error message:

> line 13, in 
> cur.executemany('INSERT INTO test_nu (vp_id, system_aktiv) VALUES(%s)', [(json.dumps(d),) for d in data])
> psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns
> than expressions LINE 1: INSERT INTO test_nu (vp_id, system_aktiv)
> VALUES('{"vp_id": ...

I've seen, that the *ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions* can have varios reasons, I was not able to solve this problem. Could the ' or {} be a problem? It seems like the json objectr doesn't get parsed *VALUES('{"vp_id": ...*  Appreciate any hint.

Comment: It does not automatically parse.  The shortest path to your goal is to use `. . . VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', (d['vp_ip'], d['system_activ'], d['vpm_activ']) for d . . . `  There is a better way to pass the entire list into your query and use the jsonb functions to do the insert.  Comment if you want to see how that is done.

Comment: I'll try it. Yes please, it would be very helpful to see how it is done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a number of round-trips to the database with the following:

```
with expand as (
  select (j->>'vp_id')::int as vp_ip,
         (j->>'system_activ')::int as system_activ,
         (j->>'vpm_activ')::int as vpm_activ
    from jsonb_array_elements((%s)::jsonb) as el(j)
)
insert into test_nu (vp_id, system_activ, vpm_activ)
select vp_ip, system_activ, vpm_activ
  from expand;
```

Pass `json.dumps(data)` to this query.

[Fiddle Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/s1Lr7eTy)

Comment: @AnthonyAdmin Sorry--I forgot to alias the result of `jsonb_array_elements()`.  I have corrected it and will set up a fiddle to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_populate_recordset`.

Refer sample query below -

```
insert into test_nu(vp_id, system_activ, vpm_activ) select * from json_populate_recordset(NULL::test_nu,'[{"vp_id": 1,"system_activ":"eewrw","vpm_activ":"qeqerqr"}]')
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/st5FE0DW).